# Current week + 1 whenever click next

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my code to whenever I click "next" arrow takes me to following week.

At the moment only does that 1 time when clicking so goes as far as week 2.

```js
//Task Manager//

var idCounter = 0
var tasksManager = {
    array: [],
    add: function(task,bracketStart,bracketEnd,date){
        taskObject = {
            title: task,
            idVerification: idCounter ++,
            startTask: bracketStart,
            endTask:bracketEnd,
            dateTask: date
        }
        tasksManager.array.push(taskObject)
    },
    show:function(id){
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < tasksManager.array.length; i++) {
           if(id === tasksManager.array[i].idVerification){
            return tasksManager.array[i]
           }
        }
    },
    delete:function(task){
       if(this.show){
       tasksManager.array.splice(task)
       }
    }
  
}

 // Calendar

 // Week Date

var myDate = new Date(),
year = myDate.getFullYear(),
month = myDate.getMonth(),
day = myDate.getDay(),
date = myDate.getDate()


var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
var dates = ["0","1st", "2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th","7th","8th","9th","10th","11th","12th","13th", "14th", "15th", "16th", "17th", "18th", "19th",
"20th", "21st", "22th", "23rd", "24th", "25th", "26th", "27th", "28th", "29th", "30th", "31st"]


var dayElement = document.createElement('div')
dayElement.innerHTML = days[day]+ "," + " "+ dates[date] + " "+ "of" + " " + months[month] +  " "  + year + "  " + "-"
document.getElementById("month-today").appendChild(dayElement)
myDate =new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth(),myDate.getDate()+7);
year = myDate.getFullYear(),
month = myDate.getMonth(),
day = myDate.getDay(),
date = myDate.getDate()
var dateText = days[day]+ "," + " "+ dates[date] + " "+ "of" + " " + months[month] +  " "  + year
document.getElementById("month-seven").innerHTML = dateText

//Week number

function getWeeksInMonth(month, year){
    var weeks=[],
        firstDate=new Date(year, month, 1),
        lastDate=new Date(year, month+1, 0), 
        numDays= lastDate.getDate();
    
    var start=1;
    var end=7-firstDate.getDay();
    while(start<=numDays){
        weeks.push({start:start,end:end});
        start = end + 1;
        end = end + 7;
        if(end>numDays)
            end=numDays;    
    }        
     return weeks;
 } 
 
 getWeeksInMonth()

 document.getElementById("week").innerHTML =getWeeksInMonth(1,2020) [0].start
 document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = year;


document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", next);
document.getElementById("prev").addEventListener("click", prev);

function next() {
myDate = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth()-1,myDate.getDate()+7);
  year = myDate.getFullYear(),
  month = myDate.getMonth(),
  day = myDate.getDay(),
  date = myDate.getDate()
  var datePlusOne = days[day]+ "," + " "+ dates[date] + " "+ "of" + " " + months[month] +  " "  + year + "  " +  "-"
document.getElementById("month-today").innerHTML = datePlusOne

 myDate =new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth(),myDate.getDate()+7);
  year = myDate.getFullYear(),
  month = myDate.getMonth(),
  day = myDate.getDay(),
  date = myDate.getDate()
  var dateText = days[day]+ "," + " "+ dates[date] + " "+ "of" + " " + months[month] +  " "  + year
document.getElementById("month-seven").innerHTML = dateText

document.getElementById("week").innerHTML =getWeeksInMonth(1,2020) [0].start + 1 
}

function prev() {
myDate = new Date(myDate - 86400000);
year = myDate.getFullYear(),
month = myDate.getMonth(),
day = myDate.getDay(),
date = myDate.getDate();
var dateText = days[day]+ "," + " "+ dates[date] + " "+ "of" + " " + months[month] +  " "  + year 
document.getElementById("month-seven").innerHTML = dateText;

myDate = new Date(myDate - 86400000 *7);
year = myDate.getFullYear(),
month = myDate.getMonth(),
day = myDate.getDay(),
date = myDate.getDate();
var dateText = days[day]+ "," + " "+ dates[date] + " "+ "of" + " " + months[month] +  " "  + year + "  " +  "-"
document.getElementById("month-today").innerHTML = dateText;
}




var button = document.getElementById("save-task")
var input = document.getElementById("add-new-task")
var startTime = document.getElementById("time-stamp")
var endTime = document.getElementById("time-stamp-finish")
var eventElement = document.querySelector('.event')
var arrows = document.querySelector('.fas')
var timeInput = document.getElementById("add-time")
var timeBar = document.querySelectorAll(".hours")

eventElement.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    document.getElementById('task-input').classList.toggle('new-task');
})

button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    tasksManager.add(input.value)
    var taskEvent = document.createElement('div')
    taskEvent.style.background = "#d25757"
    taskEvent.style.border = "1px solid black"
    taskEvent.style.padding = "30px"
    taskEvent.innerHTML = input.value
    eventElement.appendChild(taskEvent)
})

arrows.addEventListener('click', () =>{
var goBack = new Date((new Date).valueOf() - 86350989) 
console.log(goBack)
})
```

```html
<!-- Added during edit in an attempt to make it working -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ProdPlus </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tomorrow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="animated lightSpeedIn">ProdPlus+ </h1>
<div class="dropdown-menu">

</div>

<div class ="full-date">
<i class='fas fa-angle-left' id="prev"></i>
<div id="month-today"></div>
<div id="month-seven"></div>
<div id="day-today"></div>
<div id="date-today"></div>
<i class='fas fa-angle-right'id="next" ></i>
</div>

<div class ="week">
<div class ="week-text">Week</div>
<div id = "week"></div>
<div class ="week-text">of</div>
<div id= "year"></div>
</div>
<div class="new-task" id="task-input">
        <div >Task: <input id="add-new-task" type="text"></div>
        <div id="add-time"> 
            <label>Time</label>
            <select id = "time-stamp">
             <option value = "00:00">00:00</option>
             <option value = "01:00">01:00</option>
             <option value = "02:00">02:00</option>
             <option value = "03:00">03:00</option> 
              <option value = "04:00">04:00</option>
              <option value = "05:00">05:00</option>
              <option value = "06:00">06:00</option>
              <option value = "07:00">07:00</option>
              <option value = "08:00">08:00</option>
              <option value = "09:00">09:00</option>
              <option value = "10:00">10:00</option>
              <option value = "11:00">11:00</option>
              <option value = "12:00">12:00</option>
              <option value = "13:00">13:00</option>
              <option value = "14:00">14:00</option>
              <option value = "15:00">15:00</option>
              <option value = "16:00">16:00</option>
              <option value = "17:00">17:00</option>
              <option value = "18:00">18:00</option>
              <option value = "19:00">19:00</option>
              <option value = "20:00">20:00</option>
              <option value = "21:00">21:00</option>
              <option value = "22:00">22:00</option>
              <option value = "23:00">23:00</option>
            </select>
            -
            <select id = "time-stamp-finish">
            <option value = "00:00">00:00</option>
            <option value = "01:00">01:00</option>
            <option value = "02:00">02:00</option>
            <option value = "03:00">03:00</option> 
            <option value = "04:00">04:00</option>
            <option value = "05:00">05:00</option>
            <option value = "06:00">06:00</option>
            <option value = "07:00">07:00</option>
            <option value = "08:00">08:00</option>
            <option value = "09:00">09:00</option>
            <option value = "10:00">10:00</option>
            <option value = "11:00">11:00</option>
            <option value = "12:00">12:00</option>
            <option value = "13:00">13:00</option>
            <option value = "14:00">14:00</option>
            <option value = "15:00">15:00</option>
            <option value = "16:00">16:00</option>
            <option value = "17:00">17:00</option>
            <option value = "18:00">18:00</option>
            <option value = "19:00">19:00</option>
            <option value = "20:00">20:00</option>
            <option value = "21:00">21:00</option>
            <option value = "22:00">22:00</option>
            <option value = "23:00">23:00</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id = "date-stamp"> 
        Date:
        <input type="date" id="event-date" name="bday" max="2030-12-31"><br> 
        </div>
        <button class ="save-task" id ="save-task" onclick="">Save task</button>
    </div>
     <div class ="calendar">
     <div id="day-of-week">
        <div class="day" id="Monday">Monday</div>
        <div class="day"id="Tuesday">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="day"id="Wednesday">Wednesday</div>
        <div class="day"id="Thursday">Thursday</div>
        <div class="day"id="Friday">Friday</div>
        <div class="day"id="Saturday">Saturday</div>
        <div class="day"id="Sunday">Sunday</div>
     </div>
     <div class="hours">
        <div><option value = "04:00">04:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "05:00">05:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "06:00">06:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "07:00">07:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "08:00">08:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "09:00">09:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "10:00">10:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "11:00">11:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "12:00">12:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "13:00">13:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "14:00">14:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "15:00">15:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "16:00">16:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "17:00">17:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "18:00">18:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "19:00">19:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "20:00">20:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "21:00">21:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "22:00">22:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "23:00">23:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "00:00">00:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "01:00">01:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "02:00">02:00</option></div>
        <div><option value = "03:00">03:00</option></div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event event-1"></div>
            <div class="event event-2 "></div>
            <div class="event event-3"></div>
            <div class="event event-4"></div>
            <div class="event event-5"></div>
            <div class="event event-6"></div>
            <div class="event event-7"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">   
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-events">
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>          
    </div>
<div id="dates">

</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unsure how I can make it so loops through the whole year and gives me the following week number. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a working JSfiddle?

Comment: @Rpx I tried to make your code working its missing a lot of stuff. Please add whats necessary

Comment: @Gerard OP says it works first time. Means element exists. He just failed to share it. Hence requested OP to provide missing info

Comment: hey @Rajesh added all the html and js now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```js
myDate = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth(),myDate.getDate()+1);
```

do this for next week

```js
myDate = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(),myDate.getMonth()-1,myDate.getDate()+7);
```